# Unreal Engine 5 c++ GetValueTypeHash definition in TSet<customStruct>

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I a trying to create a set of structs using TSet, however,  when I compile I get the error:

The structure `X` is used in a `TSet` but does not have a `GetValueTypeHash` defined

How do I implement a `GetValueTypeHash` definition in my `struct`?

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct Fpiece
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        // Use UPROPERTY() to decorate member variables as they allow for easier integration with network replication as well as potential garbage collection processing
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Tutorial) int color;
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Tutorial) int man;
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Tutorial) int locationX;
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Tutorial) int locationY;
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Tutorial) int point;

};
```

and in public constructor:

```
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Tutorial) TSet<Fpiece> pieces;
```

Comment: Without knowing what your structure `X` is, it will be hard to tell what's the possibly best implementation for `GetValueTypeHash()` actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your solution:

```
USTRUCT()
struct Fpiece
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    int32 SomeData = 0;
};
```

and then implement like this:

```
uint32 GetTypeHash(const Fpiece& other);
{
    return FCrc::MemCrc32(&other, sizeof(Fpiece));
}
```